# How do I delete from the database in Asp.Net Core via Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, delete-row

This script is supposed to send a `ProductId` to the home controller's `Delete`-method, and the controller should make the appropriate `Remove`-operation:

```
$('[name="DeleteItem"]').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "@Url.Action('Delete','Home')",
        data: { id: $('DeleteItem#data-id').val() },
        success: function () {
            alert("success!");
            window.location.replace("@Url.Action('Index', 'Home')");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error: " + data.id);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the form:

```
<form asp-action="Update">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ShoppingCartItems)
    {
        @item.ProductTitle
        <input asp-for="@item.Quantity" />
        <button name="DeleteItem" data-id="@item.ProductId">DELETE</button>
    }
    <button type="submit">Update quantity</button>
</form>
```

This is the controller's `Delete`-method (I don't have the `ShoppingCartId`, so I'm getting it based on `SessionId`, which is stored in the `ShoppingCarts`-table):

```
[HttpDelete]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] // <-- Do I need this in this case?
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(
        [Bind("ShoppingCartItemProductId")]
        ViewModelAddToCart model)
{
    // Initialize session to enable SessionId
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Name", "MyStore");
    string SessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;

    var ShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart()
    {
        SessionId = SessionId
    };

    var ShoppingCartItem = new ShoppingCartItem()
    {
        ProductId = model.ShoppingCartItemProductId,
    };

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Find ShoppingCart containing current SessionId.
        var cartInfo =
            (from Cart in _context.ShoppingCarts
             where Cart.SessionId == SessionId
             select new { TempId = Cart.Id })
                .SingleOrDefault();
        if (cartInfo != null)
        {
            ShoppingCartItem.ShoppingCartId = cartInfo.TempId;
        }

        // Find ShoppingCartItem containing current ProductId:
        var cartItemInfo =
            (from CartItem in _context.ShoppingCartItems
             where (CartItem.ShoppingCartId == ShoppingCartItem.ShoppingCartId &&
                    CartItem.ProductId == model.ShoppingCartItemProductId)
                 select new { TempId = CartItem.Id })
                .FirstOrDefault();
        if (cartItemInfo != null)
        {
            // Delete ShoppingCartItem
            ShoppingCartItem.Id = cartItemInfo.TempId;
            _context.ShoppingCartItems.Remove(ShoppingCartItem);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

**Edit** I have made some changes to my code, and now I receive "Error: undefined" in an alert. That is because the `error:` in the ajax is triggered, and the `data`-object is not defined. Why is that? And a second question is what is the controller supposed to return? As I understand, not a `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: Your selector is invalid as there is no `<DeleteItem>` element. Presumably you mean `$('[name="DeleteItem"]')` instead. Also note that there is no `ajaxasync` attribute so that can be removed. Finally, as you're redirecting after deleting the item anyway the AJAX request itself seems a little redundant.

Comment: HttpDelete is good http verb for delete api operations

Comment: I made some changes, and now I get the error-alert, which tells me that the object `data` is undefined. I suspect I'm not getting the input value.

Comment: API Controller or View Controller?  Yes I know this is Core question but its relevant

Comment: @mvermef I don't know that I have an API Controller ..?

Comment: API vs View are differentiated now by the verbs and responses, the actual inherited controller is the same in asp.net mvc core. for example `[HttpGet]` never used in View controllers, if you did it would trigger some really interesting routing problems.  `ApiController` from asp.net mvc (v5) are now rolled into just `Controller` with core.

Comment: @mvermef So what is the right verb and response in this case?

Answer (score 1):

what is "deleteitem"

you should have some id or class for the button in your case class should be easy

```
<button name="DeleteItem" class = "deleteitemevent" data-id="@item.ProductId">DELETE</button>

$(".deleteitemevent").click(function (e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
//^^yes you should for any post... but since you insist on 
//doing ajax calls... 
//you will have to research how to build this up... from JS and inject with the ajax call..
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(
    [Bind("ShoppingCartItemProductId")]
    ViewModelAddToCart model)
{
  //...
 }


$('[name="DeleteItem"]').click(function (e) {

  var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id'); // because name was used for control not id


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action('Delete','Home')",
    data: { id: dataid },
    success: function () {
        alert("success!");
        window.location.replace("@Url.Action('Index', 'Home')");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error: " + data.id);
    }
  });
});
```

I think you have a long way to go... There are easier ways of doing this without needing ajax calls...

Comment: Yes, I clearly have a long way to go. I just started learning Asp.Net and C# less than six months ago. What other ways of refreshing parts of a web page other than Ajax are there?

Comment: When I delete with asp.net, usually will show a modal via script/bootstrap and a partial. Confirm run the backend method then `redirecttoaction`, usually `index`, therefore refreshing the screen collection.  That is the relatively smaller footprint but does incur a server operation.   Now if it where a SPA this would entirely be refreshed using javascript (not necessarily an ajax call per se).